# Is it right to say 'Share the love you have'

Tags: grammar

If I want to say to someone: 'Just share the love that you have', can I say it without 'that'? - 'Just share the love you have'?

Comment: I bet you can. What else? :) (either this is a duplicate, or the answerers will elaborate)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
And one more question))
If I want to say that the relationship has no future, can I say: We don't have a chance for tomorrow?

Comment: @Tatyana - Please ask that as a seperate question. It has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: By "just", do you mean "just share" or "just the love you have"? The first means that all she needs to do is share (not do anything else); the second means that even if she doesn't have much love that she can share, she can share, for now, "just" what little she has, and maybe it will grow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a construct where the *that* is purely optional:

> Just eat the pizza [*that*] you bought.
>   This is the car [*that*] she's always wanted.
>   This is the parade [*that*] Harold told us about.

In those three sentences, you can omit the *that*, or leave it in; the meaning will be the same.

However, this isn't the case when the *that* is followed by a **verb** instead of a noun:

> Eat the food that **was** **put** in front of you.
>   That new hotel is a place that **will open** in just ten days.
>   This is the issue that **started** the argument.

In those cases, the *that* cannot be removed, and must stay in place.

Since your example has *that* followed by a noun (you) instead of a verb, you can leave it in, or take it out.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with either of these is that "[your] love" can mean "your sweetheart/beloved".  I'm not sure you'd want to share him with someone else.

Also, there is the theory that your own love is not "had", it can only be given. This is why "the love you have" sounds not quite right, which allows the reader's mind to wander to the earlier-mentioned misapprehension.

I suggest "Just share your love." 
That doesn't give the reader much time to wander or misinterpret. (although devious minds could pretend to construe this as "spread your love around" —e.g. by sleeping with as many partners as possible")

Comment: Thank you for your answers!))
With this sentence I mean - all that you should do - just share the love that you have - and then you will feel the harmony inside you)))
I wrote a song, that's why I needed this construction - 'Just share the love you have')))
Thank you very much again for all your answers! :))